# SKAction.animation - frame order

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

А problem that caused surprise:

```
let jaba = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "jaba0")
let jabaAnimationThrow: SKAction

for i in 0...1 {
        texturesJaba.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jaba\(i)"))
    }
    jabaAnimationThrow = SKAction.animate(with: texturesJaba,
                                         timePerFrame: 0.30)
func enemyThrow(enemy: SKSpriteNode) { 
    let enemyRun = (SKAction.repeatForever((SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3, withRange: 2),jabaAnimationThrow]))))
enemy.run(enemyRun)} 
enemyThrow(enemy: jaba)
```

Problem: SCAstion.animation plays first frame 1 "jaba1", then frame 0 "jaba0"! Why?

Thank you!

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Try posting enough code to make it compile and run, so I can test it on my machine.

Comment: @GreatBigBore missing only  var texturesJaba: [SKTexture] = []

Comment: Ok, I have that variable, thanks. But I'm still not seeing the problem. I think I still need more information. Is `texturesJaba` an instance variable in a class? Is `jabaAnimationThrow` an instance variable in a class? Are `texturesJaba` and `jabaAnimationThrow` in the same class, or in different classes? Is `enemyThrow()` in the same class? If you could post enough code that I can compile with roughly the same structure as yours, that might help.

Answer (score 1):

I have compiled your code and it works just fine. Here is the steps:

1. In your GameScene.swift file set the jaba Player as follows

   ```
   override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       let jaba = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "jaba0")
       jaba.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200) // set your desired position
       jaba.setScale(0.2) // whatever scale you might need
       self.addChild(jaba)
       }
   ```
2. After that make enemyThrow(enemy: SKSpriteNode) function in GameScene.swift file as follows

   ```
   func enemyThrow(enemy: SKSpriteNode) {
           var texturesJaba = [SKTexture]()
           let jabaAnimationThrow: SKAction
           for i in 0...1 {
           texturesJaba.append(SKTexture(imageNamed: "jaba\(i)"))
           }
           jabaAnimationThrow = SKAction.animate(with: texturesJaba,
                                         timePerFrame: 0.30)
           let enemyRun =  (SKAction.repeatForever((SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 3, withRange: 2),jabaAnimationThrow]))))
   enemy.run(enemyRun)

           }
   ```
3. Lastly, in didMove(toView:) function, call enemyThrow(enemy:) function after self.addchild(jaba). The code should look like this:

   ```
    override func didMove(to view: SKView) {
       let jaba = SKSpriteNode (imageNamed: "jaba0")
       jaba.position = CGPoint(x: 100, y: 200) // set your desired position
       jaba.setScale(0.2) // whatever scale you might need
       self.addChild(jaba)

       // call the function enemyThrow here
       enemyThrow(enemy: jaba)
       }
   ```